# Attach a button action to the div it's inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> *Edit* What I'm actually asking if I can target the div my button is
>   inside without knowing the name of the id?

I want to write a javascript function that will change the properties of an INPUT box and the button itself, but I want to do this without creating a unique id for each button and each input box.

Let's say I have an onclick javascript like this

```
function changeid ()
{
var e = document.getElementById("changebutton");
e.id = "savebutton";
$('#TheAttachedDiv').attr('readonly', false);
}
function changeid ()
{
var e = document.getElementById("savebutton");
e.id = "changebutton";
$('#TheAttachedDiv').attr('readonly', true);
}
```

Because I will have 4 fields with the same class for other reasons, I don't want the properties of all CHANGE buttons and DIVS changed when I click the button besides one div.

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks

What I'm working with:

```
<div class="question active">Q1
  <input id="one" type="text">
</div>
<div class="button passive">
  <input type="button" value="Change" id="changeone" onclick="changeid()">
</div>
```

The same div repeats on and on.

Comment: What html mark-up are you working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the jQuery method [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) if you want the immediate parent or [`.parents( ... )`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) if you want to search for ancestors higher up the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like

```
jQuery('.field_same_class').click(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).attr('readonly')==false)
    {
        jQuery(this).attr('readonly',true);
        jQuery(this).next('.button_class').attr('readonly',true);
    } else {
        jQuery(this).attr('readonly',false);
        jQuery(this).next('.button_class').attr('readonly',false);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll try this and let you know :)

Comment: No, but that is amazing. I was actually looking for the .parent() function that was posted below. Thank you so much for your time anyway! That code looks great!